# Photo shared to Facebook via Open Graph has broken "app name links"

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sdk-4.0

First off: I will attempt to post as many screenshots and as many code samples as necessary to get the help that we need, thank you!

**The problem**

We have a photographic mobile app that has a setting that allows users to *automatically share their in-app photos to Facebook* when they upload them. We call these photos *moments*, and the actual sharing works just fine.

It's the app name links (are these called *attributions*?) that are broken.

In our FB app Open Graph settings, we have - amongst other objects - an object called a `moment`, an action called `share`, and a story that connects the two.

Here is what a "shared moment" looks like on FB:

[image: Moment shared on Facebook]

It's shared by our back-end server, which is based on the PHP microframework *Lumen*. Here is the relevant sharing code:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @param Moment $moment
 */
public function shareMoment(User $user, Moment $moment)
{
    $facebookAccount = $this->facebookMapper->getFacebookAccountInfo($user);
    $fb = new Facebook(array('app_id' => $this->facebookAppId, 'app_secret' => $this->facebookAppSecret));
    $postPayload = [
        'moment' => UrlUtility::getMomentOpenGraphPageUrl($moment->getGuid()),
        'fb:explicitly_shared' => true,
        'image' => [
            [
                'url' => UrlUtility::getMomentWatermarkedImageFileUrl($moment),
                'user_generated' => true
            ]
        ]
    ];
    if ($moment->hasDescription()) {
        $postPayload['message'] = $moment->getDescription();
    }
    try {
        $postPath = 'me/' . $this->facebookAppNamespace . ':share';
        $response = $fb->post($postPath, $postPayload, $facebookAccount->getAccessToken());
    } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
        ...
        return;
    }
}
```

The `getMomentOpenGraphPageUrl(...)` method provides a URL to a generated OG page containing the `moment` object metadata.

It's highly likely that the problem lies in this OG page and its metadata.

Pressing on the app link as indicated by **1** in the above screenshot results in the following:

[image: Broken FB app attribution link]

Pressing on the second app link as indicated by **2** in the above screenshot results in the following:

[image: Unwanted FB app attribution behaviour]

**To be clear:**

*We want the links to open the app if installed, or go to the app sore/our FB app page otherwise.*

In Android, this behaviour just seems to *work*. It behaves perfectly in Android. Those links open up our app. iOS is becoming a nightmare.

The 2nd link doesn't break like the 1st does, but it *links to our OG URL for the `moment` object*, which we do *not* want. We don't want *any* clicks in the FB app to go to these links as if they are a website.

We simply want the photo to be shared on FB, and the our "app name links" to act as app opening links. No external website-style behaviour.

Lastly, I'll show you the HTML that our `moment` OG page generates as referenced above (obviously CAPITALIZED items are things I have redacted):

```
<html>
<head
    prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# FBAPPNAME: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/FBAPPNAME#">
    <title>APPNAME Moment</title>

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="FB_APP_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
    <!-- <meta property="og:determiner" content="a"/> -->
    <meta property="og:description" content="A moment shared with APP NAME"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://SERVERURL.com/shared/moments/pO_8Lx3CkJY.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://SERVERURL.com/og/moment/pO_8Lx3CkJY"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="versetheapp:moment"/>

    <!-- iOS FB meta tags -->
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="IOSSCHEME://moment/372"/>
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="APP_STORE_ID"/>
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="APP NAME"/>

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #2d2d2d;
        }

        .momentImage {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="momentContainer">
    <img src="/moments/pO_8Lx3CkJY.jpg" class="momentImage"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Dying over here, it's been weeks of trying to fix this, and it's becoming an embarrassing issue in production now we allow people to share their new moments to Facebook.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: Has nothing to do with your OG story. Yes, it is called app attribution, and where it links to, depends on what platforms you have set up for your app. For canvas apps, a mobile site URL can be specified as well, but that feature was deliberately disabled by default by Facebook, because it was used to redirect users to malware sits. There is a bug report for this somewhere, which includes the link to a form where you can request your mobile site URL to get whitelisted for the app.

Comment: We have our app set up for both Android and iOS. Don't believe it's a 'canvas' app.

Comment: Also, I've been Googling this subject extensively for days and days, and have seen no reference to 'requesting to get whitelisted' for app links to work. Everything seems to suggest that the `al:ios:XXX` tags are the key..

Comment: did you find out how to solve this?